# Separate two strings from one array element

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring, nsarray

I was wondering if anyone could lend some assistance. Basically I am calling a web service and then trying to get the large hosted image url. The output from the web service is so:

```
images =     (
                {
            hostedLargeUrl = "http://i.yummly.com/Crispy-roasted-chickpeas-_garbanzo-beans_-308444.l.jpg";
            hostedSmallUrl = "http://i.yummly.com/Crispy-roasted-chickpeas-_garbanzo-beans_-308444.s.jpg";
        }
    );
```

The main problem is that the two strings are in only one of my array elements when I think they should be in 2. Also I'm not 100% but possibly they may be a dictionary :-S I'm just not sure. My code is as follows:

```
    NSArray *imageArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    imageArray = [self.detailedSearchYummlyRecipeResults objectForKey:@"images"];
    NSLog(@"imageArray: %@", imageArray);
    NSLog(@"count imageArray: %lu", (unsigned long)[imageArray count]);
    NSString *hostedLargeurlString = [imageArray objectAtIndex:0];    
    NSLog(@"imageArrayString: %@", hostedLargeurlString);
```

The output (nslog's) from the above code is:

```
2013-04-28 18:59:52.265 CustomTableView[2635:11303] imageArray: (
        {
        hostedLargeUrl = "http://i.yummly.com/Crispy-roasted-chickpeas-_garbanzo-beans_-308444.l.jpg";
        hostedSmallUrl = "http://i.yummly.com/Crispy-roasted-chickpeas-_garbanzo-beans_-308444.s.jpg";
    }
)
2013-04-28 18:59:52.266 CustomTableView[2635:11303] count imageArray: 1
2013-04-28 18:59:52.266 CustomTableView[2635:11303] imageArrayString: {
    hostedLargeUrl = "http://i.yummly.com/Crispy-roasted-chickpeas-_garbanzo-beans_-308444.l.jpg";
    hostedSmallUrl = "http://i.yummly.com/Crispy-roasted-chickpeas-_garbanzo-beans_-308444.s.jpg";
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can seperate the one element into hostedlargeUrl and hostedsmallUrl respectively?

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the images array contains a dictionary

```
images = ( 
        {
          hostedLargeUrl = "http://i.yummly.com/Crispy-roasted-chickpeas-_garbanzo-beans_-308444.l.jpg";
          hostedSmallUrl = "http://i.yummly.com/Crispy-roasted-chickpeas-_garbanzo-beans_-308444.s.jpg";
        }
);
```

so :

```
NSDictionary *d = [self.detailedSearchYummlyRecipeResults objectForKey:@"images"][0];
NSString *largeURL = d[@"hostedLargeUrl"];
NSString *smallURL = d[@"hostedSmallUrl"];
```

Comment: ...And to all those below. I may not have tried your answers but your help really is appreciated.

Comment: One more thing. Is there a way where I can basically check the type of data being held by a variable? Is there some sort of 'this is a' method that can help in such situations?

Answer (score 0):

looks like an array with in an array so

```
NSArray* links = [self.detailedSearchYummlyRecipeResults objectForKey:@"images"];
NSString* bigLink = [links objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* smallLink = [links objectAtIndex:1];
```

or it could be a dictionary

```
NSDictionary* links = [self.detailedSearchYummlyRecipeResults objectForKey:@"images"];
    NSString* bigLink = [links objectForKey:@"hostedLargeUrl "];
    NSString* smallLink = [links objectForKey:@"hostedSmallUrl "];
```

you can see the class of the object by printing out the class name

```
NSLog(@"Class Type: %@", [[self.detailedSearchYummlyRecipeResults objectForKey:@"images"] class]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `[imageArray objectAtIndex:0]` is a NSDictionary.  You've incorrectly specified it as a NSString.  You need the following:

```
  NSDictionary *hostedLarguerDictionary =
    (NSDictionary *) [imageArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

and then to access the 'large url' use:

```
   hostedLarguerDictionary[@"hostedLargeUrl"]
```

or, equivalently

```
   [hostedLarguerDictionary objectForKey: @"hostedLargeUrl"];
```